# OneLogin API to get/set a user's security policy?

Tags: api, onelogin

I can't seem to find a call in the [API docs](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/) that will give me access to get/set a user's security policy. Am I overlooking it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that via APIs currently. You can assign policy to groups and assign groups to a user though.